# QGIS plugins: dock widget layout is broken

Tags: qgis, layouts, widget

When I create QGIS plugin dockwidget UI in Qt Designer it looks OK:

[image]

But when this plugin is loaded in QGIS, all controls are small size and sticked to zero location like this:

[image]

Plugin layout is:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

found! on the root widget must place QgsDockWidget container first. And inside it all layouts panels works correctly.